# Making a feature table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two folders which has files where each file looks like this-

```
file1          file2
a 32           b  32
b 23           d  12
c 28           r  7
```

note that all letters in every word is not compulsary..they can be in any order.

Now I want to create a table of this format-

```
 a   b    c   d........r s t....   class
32  23    28  0
0    32   0   12       7 0 0 ...    0


...................................... 1
```

each row contains the alphabets value as in the file and if the alphabet is not there then 0.class 0 is for files in first folder and 1 for second folder.

My attempt-

```
import os
import pandas as pd



dir_list = "........","........"] #CHANGE INPUT PATH

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['class'])
count=0
for l in dir_list: 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(l):
        for name in files:
            outfile2 = open(root+"/"+name,'r')
            line = outfile2.readline()
            print(name)
            count+=1

            while line:
                words=line.split(" ")

                if words[0] not in df.columns:
                    df[words[0]]=words[1]

                elif words[0] in df.columns:
                    df.iloc[count-1][words[0]]=words[1]



                line = outfile2.readline()

            if l=="   ":
               df[count-1]['class']='M'
            else:
               df[count-1]['class']='B'


df=df.fillna(0)

print(df)
```

error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 34, in <module>
    df[count-1]['class']='M'
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add what is wrong with your approach?

Comment: you should read your file with pd.read_csv() and then use df.transpose() to invert indexes and columns

Comment: @CoMartel That would have worked if all the alphabets were in all the files.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob not necessarily. You could create a temporary dataframe for each file, and then concat them all

Comment: @CoMartel shape of all the dataframes would be diiferent..wont that create problems?

Comment: @Dan I ahve added

Comment: The line in the error is different from the line on your code...? `.iloc[count-1][words[0]]` vs `.iloc[count,words[0]]`

Comment: @Dan sorry I have been trying to debug the code on my own too...hence the error..I have corrected the same

Comment: So `df.iloc[count]['class']='M'` ?

Comment: @Dan since index starts from 0 therefore count-1

Comment: @ubuntu_noob I don't think so, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes

Comment: @ubuntu_noob yeah but the point was you should use `iloc`. Or just do some basic debugging and print out the index see why `0` is missing.

Comment: @Dan I added a snapshot of the files being read as dataframes.It seems as if the first line is being ignored by the pd.read_csv as index

Comment: add `print(df.index.head())` - check the type as well

Comment: @Dan on doing print(df.index.head())...this is coming AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: @ubuntu_noob ok... so I think you can figure this one out yourself. If head doesn't work then you need to check what type `index` is, and then print out the first 5 elements. Do a little debugging.